# Integrating jersey library in JBoss Application

Tags: jersey, jboss7.x, hbase

I am trying to HBase Java Client into Jboss Web Application. When I created proof of concept (POC), an standalone application, for HBase access, it did not require to integrate jersey libraries.

But when I am integrating same POC module in Jboss Web App, it threw following exception.

```
13:37:20,261 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Failed to define class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.resources.UserProvider in Module "deployment.HFPlatform.ear:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/web/resources/UserProvider (Module "deployment.HFPlatform.ear:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registerProvider(ResteasyDeployment.java:499) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registration(ResteasyDeployment.java:305) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:225) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:67) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:952) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:188) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    .
    .
    .
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/spi/inject/InjectableProvider
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
```

To fix following class issue, I added jersey jar.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/spi/inject/InjectableProvider
```

Then it start giving following problem

```
13:56:11,021 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."HFPlatform.ear".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."HFPlatform.ear".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "HFPlatform.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed.  com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClassNamesResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClasspathResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.ApplicationAdapter org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.ResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig com.sun.jersey.api.core.DefaultResourceConfig
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.scan(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:209)
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.deploy(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:101)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Standalone HBase works without jersey but this does not work with JBoss.

Answer (score 1):

Exception is saying you have more than one JAX-RS provider.
By default Jboss comes with `resteasy` jars. Remove **`resteasy`** jars from you classpath. it should work.

OR

check any other JAX-RS provider jar is in your classpath.

Comment: I want to use resteasy jars. I think jersey brings another jax-rs provider. I want to remove other jax-rs provider, which I am not able to do it. Can I ask jboss to use only resteasy jars and and ignore ohters.

Comment: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.resources.UserProvider class use jersey as JAX-RS provider.you can check code of class. 

If you are using same class then you need to use Jersey in place of resteasy.